# Server name setting for php email

Tags: php, email

I've been trying to find the location of a server name setting for website that uses php / Apache 2 on a Yosemite OS X Server.

The setting is apparent when outgoing mail (sent from a php script that is triggered when a user modifies an online account) and is visible in the name of the account that the email is being sent from.

The name of the account appears to be a default name "World Wide Web Server" and I'd like to customize this to something more appropriate.

Any suggestions about where to look would be appreciated - I've been looking and am stumped.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Apache or PHP, but how your mail/smtp server is configured. Well actually it has to do with PHP. Don't use the `mail()` function if you want configurability or reliability.

Comment: `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`